# Xtext, how to properly extend DefaultAntlrTokenToAttributeIdMapper

Tags: dsl, xtext, xtend

I am trying to provide id mapping for our web editor context for things such as detecting whether a region is hoverable or not. From my reading I figured the place to do this was with `AntlrTokenToAttributeIdMapper` and not `HighlightingCalculator`. However I have run into multiple issues implementing this. All of my files for this live in my dsl.ide package. First i created this class:

```
@Singleton
class STAntlrTokenToAttributeIdMapper extends DefaultAntlrTokenToAttributeIdMapper {

    override protected calculateId(String tokenName, int tokenType) {
        println("Calculating id for " + tokenName)
    }

}
```

Then I bound it in my `dslIdeModule`:

```
def Class<? extends DefaultAntlrTokenToAttributeIdMapper> bindDefaultAntlrTokenToAttributeIdMapper() {
        return STAntlrTokenToAttributeIdMapper
    }
```

Upon doing a jettyRun, I got this error on startup:

```
No implementation for org.eclipse.xtext.parser.antlr.ITokenDefProvider annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.contentassist.antlr.internal.Lexer.HIGHLIGHTING) was bound.
  while locating org.eclipse.xtext.parser.antlr.ITokenDefProvider annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.contentassist.antlr.internal.Lexer.HIGHLIGHTING)
    for parameter 0 at org.eclipse.xtext.ide.editor.model.TokenTypeToStringMapper.setTokenDefProvider(TokenTypeToStringMapper.java:30)
  at org.eclipse.xtext.ide.editor.model.TokenTypeToStringMapper.setTokenDefProvider(TokenTypeToStringMapper.java:30)
  at org.eclipse.xtext.service.MethodBasedModule.configure(MethodBasedModule.java:57)
```

Following the guidance provided on the xtext forum [here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&goto=706758). I added this to my runtime module:

```
def void configureHighlightingTokenDefProvider(Binder binder) {
  binder.bind(ITokenDefProvider).annotatedWith(Names.named("org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.contentassist.antlr.internal.Lexer.HIGHLIGHTING")).to(AntlrTokenDefProvider);
}
```

This caused my runtime error to go away but I am still never hitting the `calculateId` method in my token mapper. Am I doing my bindings correctly, using the right class for my purpose, or is there some other configuration I am missing?

EDIT1: It seems like it would be easy enough to do this in my HighlightingCalculator which I am already using to provide syntax highlighting. Would there be any reason not to use it instead of the antlrTokenToAttributeIdMapper?

EDIT2: I made the suggested change for my binding to

```
def void configureHighlightingTokenDefProvider(Binder binder) {  
    binder.bind(ITokenDefProvider).annotatedWith(Names.named(LexerIdeBindings.HIGHLIGHTING)).to(AntlrTokenDefProvider);
}
```

But I am still not hitting my mapping class

Comment: Looks Like you Need to subclass the Other Mapper clas (UiPackage)

Comment: => there are two classes. one in the ide package, one in the ui. make sure you customize the correct ones

Comment: Yes that was definitely incorrect, I should be using the one from xtext.ide.

Answer (score 1):

something like

```
class MyDslIdeModule extends AbstractMyDslIdeModule {

    def Class<? extends DefaultAntlrTokenToAttributeIdMapper>
bindDefaultAntlrTokenToAttributeIdMapper() {
        MyDslAntlrTokenToAttributeIdMapper
    }

    def void configureHighlightingTokenDefProvider(Binder binder) {
        binder.bind(ITokenDefProvider).annotatedWith(Names.named(LexerIdeBindings.HIGHLIGHTING)).to(
            AntlrTokenDefProvider);
    }
}
```

should work

Comment: I changed my binding to that and the error is gone, but my calculateId method is still not being hit. Correct me if I am wrong but this should be used automatically by xtext/web framework? It is not something I need to manually make calls to? Same as highlighting and the highglightingCalculator

Comment: Hm, So I guess there is something wrong with my underlying assumption that this is something the framework pulls in on its own. I removed all of my bindings and debugged, but even the default/abstract token mapper is not being hit. It is hard to tell when and how this is supposed to be used as I couldn't find any documentation besides forum posts. Btw Christian, thank you for your continued support as I am learn the nuances of xtext

Comment: The framework pulls only holds true for default configs

Comment: I see, well I was able to get the functionality I needed by using the SemanticHighlightingCalculator. Still a little confused on the intended use case for each class, but I have probably used up enough of your time for today :) Thanks again!